# Why the output of the following code is "No"?

Tags: c

I have done this code in my VS-code using Mingw GCC compiler and I got the output "No" instead of "Yes"? It is clear that 5>4>3, then what is the reason behind it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    if (5 > a > 3)
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");
    return 0;
}
```

```
Expected Output: Yes
Original Output: No
```

Comment: Because `5 > a > 3` in C is not the same as in math. It is evaluated as `(5 > a) > 3`, which is false

Comment: "It is clear that 5>4>3" -> No.  `5>4` is `1` and `1 >3` is 0.

Comment: Python is probably the only reasonably popular language where this works the way you expect.

Comment: I don't know if it was a sincere attempt to "recycle" an old question, a vengeful attempt to ridicule decision to close, or a plain vandalism. But, just in case it was an honest mistake, you can't edit your question to replace it by one totally different and unrelated (about time complexity of '*' printing). I rolled back to the original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(5 > a > 3)` does not mean what you think it means.  It translates to `(5>a) > 3`, and `(5>a)` evaluates to `1`.  Then, `1>3` evaluates to false, so you get "No".

To do what you want, you do `if ( (5 > a) && (a > 3) )`.